# How to read a compressed (gz) CSV file into a dask Dataframe?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dask

Is there a way to read a .csv file that is compressed via gz into a dask dataframe?

I've tried it directly with

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("Data.gz" )
```

but get an unicode error (probably because it is interpreting the compressed bytes) There is a `"compression"` parameter but `compression = "gz"` won't work and I can't find any documentation so far.

With pandas I can read the file directly without a problem other than the result blowing up my memory ;-) but if I restrict the number of lines it works fine.

```
import pandas.Dataframe as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Data.gz", ncols=100)
```

Comment: Well, the regular pandas (non-dask) reads is fine without any encoding set, so my guess would be that dask tries to read the compressed gz file directly as an ascii file and gets non-sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's actually a long-standing limitation of [dask](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2554#issuecomment-333475231). Load the files with `dask.delayed` [instead](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2554#issuecomment-317805727):

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed

filenames = ...
dfs = [delayed(pd.read_csv)(fn) for fn in filenames]

df = dd.from_delayed(dfs) # df is a dask dataframe
```

Comment: I believe the question was about a single gz (which works) not zip file (zip was mentioned as a limitation in the linked GitHub issue). Is there still any advantage using delayed in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I wanted to delete my answer but I couldn't because it's the accepted answer.

Comment: btw: zip will be supported as soon as https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/5064 goes in

Answer (score 28):

Panda's current documentation says:

> compression : {‘infer’, ‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘zip’, ‘xz’, None}, default ‘infer’

Since 'infer' is the default, that would explain why it is working with pandas.

Dask's documentation on the *compression* argument:

> String like ‘gzip’ or ‘xz’. Must support efficient random access. Filenames with extensions corresponding to known compression algorithms (gz, bz2) will be compressed accordingly automatically

That would suggest that it should also infer the compression for at least *gz*. That it doesn't (and it still does not in 0.15.3) may be a bug. However, it is working using compression='gzip'.

i.e.:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("Data.gz", compression='gzip')
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the file it's difficult to say. what if you set the encoding `like # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-`? or since `read_csv` is based off of Pandas, you may even `dd.read_csv('Data.gz', encoding='utf-8')`. Here's the list of Python encodings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: well, good idea, but still get the error:
    'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte.
When I decompress the file on disk and read it it almost works but for complaints about NaN types

Comment: @Magellan88: how about adding `error_bad_lines=False`