# Dask dataframe from delayed zip csv

Tags: pandas, dask, zip, dask-delayed

I am trying to create a dask dataframe from a set of zipped CSV files. Reading up on the problem, it seems that dask needs to use dask.distributed delayed()

```
import glob
import dask.dataframe as dd
import zipfile
import pandas as pd 
from dask.delayed import delayed

#Create zip_dict with key-value pairs for .zip & .csv names
file_list = glob.glob('my_directory/zip_files/')
zip_dict = {}
for f in file_list:
    key = f.split('/')[5][:-4]
    zip_dict[key] = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
```

> sample contents of zip_dict = {'log20160201':
>   zipfile.ZipFile  filename='/my_directory/zip_files/log20160201.zip'
>   mode='r',  'log20160218': zipfile.ZipFile 
>   filename='/my_directory/zip_files/log20160218.zip' mode='r'}

```
# Create list of delayed pd.read_csv()    
d_rows = []
for k, v in zip_dict.items():

    row = delayed(pd.read_csv)(v.open(k+'.csv'),usecols=['time','cik'])
    d_rows.append(row)
    v.close()
```

> the sample contents of d_rows =
>   [Delayed('read_csv-c05dc861-79c3-4e22-8da6-927f5b7da123'), 
>   Delayed('read_csv-4fe1c901-44b4-478b-9c11-4a80f7a639e2')]

```
big_df = dd.from_delayed(d_rows)
```

The error being returned is:
**ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: class 'list'**

Comment: Hi there. It might be helpful to post some additional information about the filenames. I noticed you seem to be storing the file names in `zip_dict`. Could you post the contents of `zip_dict` with `for k, v in zip_dict.items(): print(k)` to show the `*.csv` file names? Also, it looks to me like you want to vertically concatenate all the files into a single `dask` dataframe. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am trying to create a single dask dataframe. I have updated the original post with additional details.

Answer (score 5):

### High-level approach

In this case, I don't think you actually require the dictionary `zip_dict` to lazily read in these zipped files with Pandas. Based on [this very similar SO question to read in (`.gz`) compressed `*.csv` files using Dask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52417490/4057186) (also shown [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html#working-with-collections)), and since you have multiple files to be loaded, there are at least two possible approaches available to you

1. use `dask.delayed` and `pandas.read_csv`

   - here, you can read each file into a `pandas.DataFrame`, but rather than actually performing the read into memory, you would delay this operation, thereby creating a list of delayed objects (there are at least two ways to create this list as shown below)

     - to create a list with a `for` loop, this is something like `[delayed(pd.read_csv)(f) for f in file_list]`

       - if you have 17 `.csv.zip` files, then this creates a list of 17 delayed objects
     - to create a list with `map` and `functools.partial`, this creates a single-element list and looks like `list(map(functools.partial(delayed(pd.read_csv), file_list)))`

       - if you have 17 `.csv.zip` files, then this creates a list of 1 delayed object
   - then you use `dd.from_delayed` to convert this list of delayed objects into a `pandas.DataFrame`

     - with the looping approach this is similar to `dd.from_delayed(dfs)`
     - with the `map()` and `functools.partial` approach, you would use `dd.from_delayed(dfs).repartition(file_list)`

       - since this approach only gives a single-(delayed)element list, the resulting `dask.dataframe` will have the effect of vertically concatenating all the files into a single `dask.dataframe` partition
       - in order to separate each of the 17 files into a dedicated partition of the `dask.dataframe`, you would need to use `.repartition()`
2. use `dask.dataframe.read_csv(file_list)` [directly](https://gist.github.com/kadekillary/550a7fbcce803135e4a082e19b7fddcb), which actually uses `pandas.read_csv` and so it accepts many of the keyword arguments from `pandas.read_csv`

In both of these approaches

- it is a Dask best-practice to specify the `dtypes` of the columns ([as recommended](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_delayed)) that will be read in

  - you can do this with a dictionary, which would look like `{"time": int, "cik": int}`, since you only need the columns `time` and `cik` and you know that each of them is expected to be of `int` (integer) `dtype`
- use the `.read_csv()` keyword

  - `usecols` to specify a list of column names that are needed
  - `compression` to indicate that a `.zip` file is being read in

### Python Code

Below is the code to implement each of these approaches with brief comments as required

#### Imports

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import repeat
from glob import glob
from collections import OrderedDict

import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask.delayed import delayed
```

#### Generate dummy data files

Using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10834984/4057186), generate multiple `.csv` files

```
def generate_multiple_csvs(data_dir, file_num=1):
    col_names = list("ABCDEFG")+["time", "cik"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,9)), columns=col_names)
    filename = f"data_file_{file_num}.csv.zip"
    filepath = data_dir + "/" + filename
    df["filepath"] = filename
    df.to_csv(filepath, index=False, compression="zip")
    return df

# Specify path the directory where `.csv.zip` files should be created
data_dir = "data/processed"

# Specify number of files to create
num_files_wanted = 8
```

Use `itertools.repeat` to create dummy files

```
_ = list(
    map(
        generate_multiple_csvs,
        repeat(data_dir, num_files_wanted),
        list(range(1, num_files_wanted+1)),
    )
)
```

Use `functools.partial` to create dummy files

```
_ = list(
    map(
        partial(generate_multiple_csvs, data_dir),
        list(range(9, 9+num_files_wanted+1)),
    )
)
```

#### Get list of files by filetype

```
file_list = glob(data_dir + "/" + "*.zip")
```

#### Specify column `dtypes` for columns in Dask DataFrame (recommended)

```
my_dtypes = OrderedDict([("time",int), ("cik",int)])
```

#### Approach 1 - Using `dask.delayed` with a `for` loop

```
# Lazily reading files into Pandas DataFrames by looping
dfs = [
    delayed(pd.read_csv)(f, compression='zip', usecols=['time','cik'])
    for f in file_list
]

# Combine into a single Dask DataFrame
ddf_from_delayed_loop = dd.from_delayed(dfs, meta=my_dtypes)

print(type(ddf_from_delayed_loop))
print(ddf_from_delayed_loop)
```

Output

```
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                 time    cik
npartitions=17              
                int64  int64
                  ...    ...
...               ...    ...
                  ...    ...
                  ...    ...
Dask Name: from-delayed, 34 tasks
```

#### Approach 1 - Using `dask.delayed` with `map`

```
# Lazily reading files into Pandas DataFrames with Python's built-in map()
dfs = list(
    map(
        partial(
            delayed(pd.read_csv),
            compression="zip",
            usecols=['time', 'cik'],
        ),
        file_list,
    )
)

# Combine into a single Dask DataFrame and repartition
ddf_from_delayed_map = dd.from_delayed(dfs, meta=my_dtypes).repartition(
    npartitions=len(file_list)
)

print(type(ddf_from_delayed_map))
print(ddf_from_delayed_map)
```

Output

```
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                 time    cik
npartitions=17              
                int64  int64
                  ...    ...
...               ...    ...
                  ...    ...
                  ...    ...
Dask Name: from-delayed, 34 tasks
```

#### Approach 2 - Directly using `dask.dataframe`

```
# Lazily reading files into single Dask DataFrame
ddf_direct = dd.read_csv(
    data_dir+"/*.csv.zip",
    compression='zip',
    dtype=my_dtypes,
    blocksize=None,
    usecols=['time','cik'],
)

print(type(ddf_direct))
print(ddf_direct)
```

Output

```
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                 time    cik
npartitions=17              
                int64  int64
                  ...    ...
...               ...    ...
                  ...    ...
                  ...    ...
Dask Name: read-csv, 17 tasks
```

### Notes

1. For all of the above approaches, specifying the number partitions should be done with the following in mind

   - dask best-practices

     - [choosing the optimal partition size](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html#repartition-to-reduce-overhead) ([basics of this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58546985/4057186))
     - [avoid large computation graphs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-very-large-graphs)
     - [avoid large partitions](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-very-large-partitions)
   - [factors to keep in mind for large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59128929/4057186)
2. Use [batching for the `dask.delayed` approach with a `for` loop](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#avoid-too-many-tasks) in order to cut back on overhead from a large number of calls to `dask.delayed` (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453201/how-do-the-batching-instructions-of-dask-delayed-best-practices-work) for batching implementation).